# Is it possible to send message(xml or JSON) between android devices without the Internet

Tags: android, json, client-server

I wanted to create an app that sends messages between multiple android devices, where preferably one is the server and the remaining are clients, that are connected to the same network but without internet access. The message maybe String or XML or JSON. I have already tried ServerSocket programs with the help of internet  connection and but wanted to do it without the Internet factor. 
Moreover, since multiple clients might send data or requests to the Server, is there any API to handle the concurrent access or do we need to manually synchronize it?

Any response would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What about bluetooth?

Comment: Bluetooth has lower connectivity range and i need to have a central server device that gets all the requests or messages and sends response to them accordingly. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: I guess NFC is out, too.  I think your only other option is 3G, LG, 4G or other phone network.

Comment: I have tried those, currently I am trying to test the NSD api for the feasibility. Do you know whether NSD requires internet connection?

Comment: I don't know anything about NSD.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The following articles is the one from where i am learning NSD implementations.
http://www.obsessivelyandroid.com/?p=145